# How to draw on screen NASM?

Tags: macos, assembly, graphics, nasm, x86-64

**Before you read the question body**: I understand that there are tons of graphics libraries out there that work a lot faster than mine. This question is asked in *educational* purposes (honestly, I’m kinda lazy, so I don’t wanna learn how to use libraries). "Use OpenGL" isn’t an answer to my question.

I’m learning NASM programming and I want to open a window and draw in it. I couldn’t find the answer anywhere on the web. So, is it possible to do that using interrupts and/or reading/writing commands/colors to some memory addresses? I have iMac, so Windows functions probably won’t work.

Comment: Any modern OS (like OS X) will NOT allow user code to directly access the HW peripherals, so you can't access your graphics card, or kernel screen buffer, directly (like some kind of interrupt or just memory manipulation). That said, you wouldn't even want to, because every modern gfx card has different way of interacting, so you need specific code to draw with each card. That's not a problem with modern OS, which certainly provides some system services, how to draw common geometric elements on screen (into window). So look what kind of OS API is available to draw and where to.

Comment: Are you talking about assembling a program to run as an executable on your OS? In that case, it's going to be extremely platform-specific, and probably involve linking against and calling system libraries/calls.

Comment: BTW, OpenGL is quite easy to learn... lot more simpler, than writing graphics driver for something like nVidia GeForce card.

Comment: @Ped7g Unfortunately, Apple stopped supporting OpenGL, so that’s not an option either.

Comment: If you want to display a window and draw on it, simply use [CoreGraphics](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics). Even if you could access the framebuffer through some device node, you still would not be able to interact with the windowing system.

Comment: @GoingToDark: Are you sure about that?  That seems incredibly unlikely, and **https://developer.apple.com/opengl/ says "OpenGL is the foundation for hardware-accelerated graphics in macOS"**.  (You don't have to use it *directly*, though.  As Margaret says, CoreGraphics might be what you want.)

Comment: @PeterCordes This page (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_intro/opengl_intro.html), which is linked in the page you stated says that OpenGL is no longer supported. I found info that on macOS is OpenGL 2.7 (or something like this) and the latest one is 3.3.

Comment: If you prefer a lower level access, Apple introduced [Metal](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal) (as a competitor or substitute of OpenGL) a few years ago.

Comment: @GoingToDark: "deprecated" is a *long* way from "not supported".  There are a huge number of OpenGL applications in existence, and it's extremely unlikely that they'll stop working on the next version of OS X.  But thanks for the link, that's interesting.  https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht202823 says that current Macs (since ~2012) support OpenGL 4.1, and older ones support OpenGL 3.3.